# How to find if sequence of numbers is ascending or descending

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, sequence

and im really struggling with this task last few hours (+ - 10 hours).
Write a program that reads a sequence of integer numbers and outputs true if the sequence is ordered (in ascending or descending order), otherwise, false. Keep in mind, if a number has the same value as the following number, it does not break the order.

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = scanner.nextInt();

    int i = 0;
    boolean isOrdered = true;
    int previous = 0;
    int current = 0;

    while (a != 0) {
        while (i > a) {
            current = scanner.nextInt();   
            if (current < previous) {
                isOrdered = false;
            }else {
                previous = current;
                i++;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I used 2 numbers and tried to use one of them as reference,

 i created  while loop to check if  i != 0 
in my logic I did few  if conditions to check as it follows 

if (firstNum > secondNum ) {
   firstNum = scan.nextInt();
  

and then another check if the new first num is bigger than the  second number  and etc etc. however im having troubles defining how to do 1 check if they are ascending or descending. In my output i get  5 times true / 5 times false if i do input as it follows
 
input : 1 2 3 4 5  0
output : TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Comment: If you can please update question and put above content to it. Also paste the code you were trying, it will help answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detect if the numbers are both ascending and descending. If both, you need to return `false`, otherwise you return `true`.

To do that, you need two `boolean` variables.

Pseudo-code:

```
isAscending = false
isDescending = false
loop values:
    if value > previousValue:
        isAscending = true
    else if value < previousValue:
        isDescending = true
if isAscending and isDescending:
    return false
return true
```

<sup>*This is basically what my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845203/5221149) does, using code trickery.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small compact way to do it. Not very efficient, since it has no short-circuit logic. See if you can understand how it works.

```
static boolean isOrdered(int... input) {
    int[] counts = new int[3];
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
        ++counts[1 + Integer.signum(Integer.compare(input[i - 1], input[i]))];
    return (counts[0] == 0 || counts[2] == 0);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(isOrdered(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32));   // true (ascending, no equals)
System.out.println(isOrdered(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)); // true (ascending, with equals)
System.out.println(isOrdered(9, 7, 7, 5, 3, 3, 1));  // true (decending, with equals)
System.out.println(isOrdered(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5));     // true (all equal)
System.out.println(isOrdered(1, 3, 5, 2, 9, 11));    // false
```

*Output*

```
true
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: I posted the code above, with some help from you guys I figured half of the task, now i need to stop the program if 0 is entered  and  i assume i should do one more if inside the loop that checks

    if (current == 0){
       break;
}
I think ill figure out how to do the descending order, thanks for the help and sorry if it was wacky post,its my first time posting and i was struggling a lot on this, now i have some basic guideline to follow !